# Getting "no current user" while i am navigating from a screen to another screen in aws-amplify-react-native

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Getting "no current user" while i am navigating from a screen to another screen in aws-amplify-react-native.

I am using `Auth.currentSession()` from amplify and Authenticator from aws-amplify-react-native.

Here my package .json shows the version as

```
"aws-amplify": "^3.0.11",
 "aws-amplify-react-native": "^4.1.2",
 "aws-sdk": "^2.681.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added auth? In case yes you will need also amazon-cognito-identity-js.
If still not working check you have done your signUp and signIn correctly. Check also the permissions of your user Roles with the IAM on AWS.